# php session variables called in javascript not saved

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

```
<?php 
echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(){
    alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['count'] ?>);
    <?php $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count']+1 ?>;
}
</script>
...
<div>
    <button name="a" onclick="a()" type="button">a1</button>
</div>
```

this code dosen't work, the changes in session variable 'count' cannot save and every time I call alert, it bubbles "1";
How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client side and serve side. This is hugely important in web development.

Comment: So I need to update session varible by button?

Comment: Right click -> view page source. Then you will see the source and maybe understand what are you trying to do :)